# Inputing an MPLD3 graph into Wordpress

Tags: python, html, wordpress, d3.js, matplotlib

I'm having trouble getting my **mpld3** plot to show up in my **Wordpress** page. I make my plot, then use `mpld3.save_html()` to get an html file that contains my figure. However, when I paste this code into my Wordpress page (using the Text editor, not the visual editor) nothing happens. I paste both the script and div tags. I know my javascript is working because I can write `alert('Hello');` inside script tags, which works fine. I've also tried installing the "Insert Javascript & CSS" plugin, which also did not work.

Is there some way to embed these graphs into **Wordpress**, and if not, how does one embed interactive charts in a **Wordpress** post?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the d3.js and mpld3.js were not found, which would explain why you don't see the chart.
There is a d3_url and mpld3_url that you may want to provide and set to the url of a CDN where the files are available for example See https://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.fig_to_html

Even after setting that properly you may have problems as this is not the recommended way to use javascript within wordpress. You can also try an embed with stricter separation from wordpress: see http://www.datamaplab.com/posts/embedding-javascript-visualization-wordpress/ for reference.